# Перевод строки после разделителя в верхний регистр

Tags: delphi

**Почему неправильно работает цикл:**

А именно если в **edit1** указываю два знаки - **;:** и обрабатываю строки

```
StroKa1:StroKa2
StroKa3;StroKa4
StroKa5:StroKa6
```

**То получаю неверный результат**

```
STROKA1:STROKA2
STROKA3;STROKA4
STROKA5:STROKA6
```

**А должно быть так** - В верхнем регистре должно быть все после **знаков - :;**

```
StroKa1:STROKA2
StroKa3:STROKA4
StroKa5:STROKA6
```

**Код:**

```
Var
s,r:String;
z:Integer;

r:=Edit1.Text;
for z := 1 to Length(r) do
begin
s := Copy(s,1,(Pos(r[z],s) )) + AnsiUpperCase(Copy(s,(Pos(r[z],s))+1));
end;
```

**А когда без цикла тот же код то работает:**

```
s := Copy(s,1,(Pos(';',s) or Pos(':',s))) + AnsiUpperCase(Copy(s,(Pos(';',s) or Pos(':',s))+1));
```

**Но нужно именно с циклом. В чем же проблема ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант 1:**

```
procedure TForm1.Btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  Str: String;
  DelimeterIndex: Integer;
begin
  Str := Edit1.Text;

  DelimeterIndex := MaxInt;
  for I := 1 to Length(Str) do
  begin
    if (Str[I] = '*') then
      DelimeterIndex := MaxInt;

    if (Str[I] = ';') or (Str[I] = ':') then
      DelimeterIndex := I;

    if I > DelimeterIndex then
      Str[I] := UpCase(Str[I]);
  end;

  Edit2.Text := Str;
end;
```

**Вариант 2:**

```
procedure TForm1.Btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  Str: String;
  DelimeterIndex: Integer;
begin
  DelimeterIndex := MaxInt;
  SetLength(Str, Length(Edit1.Text));

  for I := 1 to Length(Edit1.Text) do
  begin
    if (Edit1.Text[I] = '*') then
      DelimeterIndex := MaxInt;

    if (Edit1.Text[I] = ';') or (Edit1.Text[I] = ':') then
      DelimeterIndex := I;

    if I <= DelimeterIndex then
      Str[I] := Edit1.Text[I]
    else
      Str[I] := UpCase(Edit1.Text[I])
  end;

  Edit2.Text := Str;
end;
```

Comment: ответ хороший. Но суть задания в том что бы программа брала в цикле значения из edit1. То есть в Edit1 находятся знаки (:;).

Comment: @MaksimGurov Эм... а результат куда? тоже в Edit1?

Comment: Тут идет открытия текстового файла, в edit1 указываем разделители после которых переводить текст в верхний регистр. И запись в другой текстовый файл - результат.

Comment: Так давайте пока без файлов.. У вас есть edit1 со строкой вида `StroKa1:StroKa2` или `StroKa1;StroKa2`. Вот после преобразования где должна оказаться новая строка? В переменой? В edit1?

Comment: Если так то В переменой... То есть по сути дела Edit должен служить для ввода знаков после каких переводить в верхний регистр строки.

Comment: @MaksimGurov В ответе эта переменная `Str`. Я просто для наглядности присвоил её значение в другой Edit, но вы можете делать с ней все что угодно

Comment: @MaksimGurov Добавил вариант с чтением из Edit1(Хотя первый вариант лутше).

Comment: Смотрите, наверное Вы меня неправильно поняли. А если  разделителей в edit будет 10 или 20 то каждый раз их в коде менять ? Я имел в виду что сделать так что бы можно было в edit вводить постоянно разные символы. А у вас они фиксируются, не берутся из Edit в цикле. Заранее благодарен за понимание.

Comment: @MaksimGurov То есть в edit может быть несколько пар `StroKa1:StroKa2`?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: @MaksimGurov Так это понятно. Чем пары разделяются? Пробелами?

Comment: Пары идут без пробелом, все слитно: Так можно сделать ? К примеру знаки ;:-+

Comment: @MaksimGurov Без разделителя пар ни как. Например `StroKa1:StroKa2StroKa3;StroKa4`. Можно взять какой то символ как раздилеть пар на пример *. То есть будет как то так `StroKa1:StroKa2*StroKa3;StroKa4`

Comment: Давайте, тогда с разделителем пар. На ваше усмотрение...

Comment: @MaksimGurov исправил

Comment: Спасибо большое. Принял Ваш ответ.